# How to transfer realtime audio stream to server using android

Tags: android, android-layout, audio-streaming

How to transfer realtime audio stream to server using android?
is there a way to send audio through an android app to a server so that people can access it online

Comment: I suggest creating an Icecast source client, which these days is as easy as encoding your data and doing an HTTP PUT.